# Слово "променадша"

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Как можно охарактеризовать слово *променадша*? Чем близким по смыслу его можно заменить?

Comment: Променад -- прогулка?

Comment: Вы хотя бы смысл оного слова раскрыли.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего окказионализм (слово "по случаю"), хотя не могу исключать его наличие в каком-либо жаргоне или диалекте (правда сильно сомневаюсь). В объясняющем обрамлении подобное образование вполне возможно использовать для иронического наименования особы, совершающей променад, но в отрыве от контекста слово может быть непонятно, как, например, в данном вопросе.

Comment: @Бегемот, Аер, Маркиз... Контекст - самый что ни на есть подходящий. Голая старуха демонстративно прогуливалась по самой людной улице Панамы - столице одноименной страны.

Comment: @Виктор, просьба не коверкать ники участников. После ввода знака @ и пары символов, ник обозначается полностью.

Comment: @Виктор - mon cher ami, благопристойная "прогулка" никак не может быть тем же самым контекстом для кича, будирования, демонстрации, провокации

Comment: Даже как оказионализм слово вызывает протест способом образования: по смыслу оно может быть понято только как "жена обладателя фамилии Променад". Если же имеется в виду прогуливающаяся дама, то с подобной иронией лучше какая-нибудь "променадчица": "променадчика" даже гугл находит у одного самодеятельного литератора. Пикет - пикетчица, променад - променадчица, раз уж надо.

Answer (score 0):

Это совершенно бессмысленный в своей глупости варваризм (да простят меня профессионалы за не совсем корректное употребление термина)!

В чем глупость/идиотизм данного "словообразования"?

1. Основа "променад" - многозначна. Это a) устаревшее (францизм) наименование прогулки по городу б) *место для прогулок* в больших городах /совр. - см. "Сочинский променад"/ в) фигура в кадрили г) с конца 19 века - "легкий ужин в общепите"
2. Совершенно варварское нерусское словоообразование. В качестве примера, чтобы не грузить теорией: "сидящая на вахте" (где вахта - "точка допуска") - вахта - вахтер - вахтерша. Видим разницу?

Таким образом, "променадша" - или просто "прогуливающаяся" или "работница/служащая променада /как места прогулки/"+ еще коннотация "бандерша" (мне в голову лезет)

В любом случае - новояз, для пояснения которого требуется больше знаков, чем для альтернативной однозначной словоформы

Comment: Пожалуйста, старайтесь использовать более нейтральную лексику.

Comment: @ Lazy Badger Так я и прошу предложить достойную (!)  замену, или синоним.

Answer (score 0):

Если бы "променадом" назывался человек, то "променадша" была бы его жена или, как сейчас употребляют это окончание, этот же человек женского пола. Но если "променад" это прогулка, то никакой "променадши" быть не может.

Comment: «Не может быть» и не должно быть никогда— здесь уже написано. Что-то свежее есть?

Comment: Ув. Редискин, спасибо за запоздалое разъяснение, слово из текста уже удалил.